# jQuery timer not displaying correctly when I resume after pressing the back arrow

Tags: php, jquery, timer

I have a jQuery countdown timer function that is calling the value of a query in a php file in the same file. But this timer is not displaying time left when I resume the question after I had press the back button. I echoed the query and I found out that the values were fetched but the timer is not resuming rather it displays "Time's up!!!\nPlease Submit your Answers".

Please does anyone knows whats going on and how I can fix this?

[image: screen shot]

The Query section.

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student_class_quiz WHERE student_id = '$session_id' and class_quiz_id = '$class_quiz_id'")or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $quiz_time = $row['student_quiz_time'];

    $sqlp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class_quiz WHERE class_quiz_id = '$class_quiz_id'")or die(mysql_error());
    $rowp = mysql_fetch_array($sqlp);
    if($quiz_time <= $rowp['quiz_time'] AND $quiz_time > 0) {
         mysql_query("UPDATE student_class_quiz SET student_quiz_time = ".$row['student_quiz_time']." - 1 WHERE student_id = '$session_id' and class_quiz_id = '$class_quiz_id'")or die(mysql_error()); 
        /* $_SESSION['take_exam'] = 'continue'; */

        $init = $quiz_time;
        $minutes = floor(($init / 60) % 60);
        $seconds = $init % 60;
        if($init > 59) {        
            echo "$minutes minutes and $seconds seconds";
        } else {
            echo "$seconds seconds";
        }
    }/* else {
        $_SESSION['take_exam'] = 'denied';
    } */
    ?>
```

The Timer section

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var timer = 1;
    jQuery(".questions-table input").hide();
    setInterval(function() {
        var timer = jQuery("#timer").text();
        jQuery("#timer").load("take_test.php #ajax");   

        if(timer == 0) {
            jQuery(".questions-table input").hide();
            jQuery("#submit-test").show();
            jQuery("#msg").text("Time's up!!!\nPlease Submit your Answers");
        } else {
            jQuery(".questions-table input").show();
        }
    },990); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_` functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (released in June, 2013 and so old it doesn't receive security updates anymore) and removed completely in PHP 7. Instead, use the `mysqli_` functions or PDO.

Comment: could you also include the code where you echo out the `timer` element?